# How can marge these loop code?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I just need an idea where to put this code:

```
$term_featured_image_id = get_term_meta( $custom_term->ID, 'wp_travel_trip_type_image_id', true );
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $term_featured_image_id );
```

In This code:

```
<?php
$post_type = 'itineraries';
$custom_tax = 'travel_locations';
$custom_args = array(
'parent' => 0
);
$custom_terms = get_terms($custom_tax, $custom_args);
                    foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
                        $term_link = get_term_link( $custom_term  );
                        wp_reset_query();
                        $args = array('post_type' => 'itineraries',
                                      'tax_query' => array(
                                          array(                                                  
                                              'taxonomy' => 'travel_locations',
                                              'field' => 'slug',
                                              'terms' => $custom_term->slug,                                                  

                                              ),
                                          ),
                                     ); ?>
                    <?php 
                        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                        if($loop->have_posts()) { ?>
<?php
while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
//some content here
<?php
endwhile;?>
<?php } }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how you could use your first code in the second one. In my code I also took the liberty to suggest one way of making your code more clear and easier to read by splitting the code into separate functions.

```
// add the following helper functions to functions.php
function travel_trip_type_image_url( int $term_id ) {
  $img_id = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'wp_travel_trip_type_image_id', true );
  return ( $img_id && is_int($img_id) ) ? wp_get_attachment_url( $img_id ) : '';
}

function travel_location_terms() {
  $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'travel_locations',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'     => 0
  ) );
  return ( $terms && ! is_wp_error($terms) ) ? $terms : array();
}

function itineraries_query( string $term ) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'itineraries',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(                                                  
        'taxonomy' => 'travel_locations',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $term,
      ),
    ),
  );
  return new WP_Query($args);
}

function itineraries_loop( WP_Query $query ) {
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {      
      $query->the_post();
      the_title('<h2>','</h2>');
      // use get_template_part( 'your-post-entry-template' ); 
      // or write html markup here
    }    
    wp_reset_postdata();    
  }
}

function travel_type_header( WP_Term $term ) {
  if ( $term_img_url = travel_trip_type_image_url( $term->term_id ) ) {
    // modify html output as needed
    printf(
      '<a href="%s"><img src="%s" alt="%s"></a>',
      esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ),
      esc_url( $term_img_url ),
      esc_attr( $term->name )
    );
  }
}

// use in some template file
foreach ( travel_location_terms() as $travel_location ) {
  travel_type_header( $travel_location );
  itineraries_loop( itineraries_query( $travel_location->slug ) );  
}
```

But if you don't want to use the suggested split, then just put your first code between the `foreach` and `$term_link` lines.

To use this code you need to

1. check and, if needed, update the meta key used in `travel_trip_type_image_url()`,
2. check and, if needed, update `taxonomy` and `post type` names used in code,
3. update the loop entry html output inside `itineraries_loop()` to your liking,
4. update the term header html output inside `travel_type_header()` to your liking,
5. have terms and post in your custom taxonomy and post type.

Comment: Thank you sir for help, but please define this function without putting in function.php. I tried with function.php but it's not worked!

Comment: @KaranKcoresys In the case you don't want to use the code example I posted, just read the last line of my answer. You should be able to just add your first code inside the foreach loop of your second code.

Comment: @KaranKcoresys Could you be more specific with the code "not working", please? What did you do with the code exactly? Did you just copy-paste it or tweaked it to match your setup? Did you get any output? Or errors?

Comment: thank you sir for the reply, I am using the plugin named wptravel. i tried many things but not able to get taxonomy featured image in to the page.

I used to put first code after foreach. but i don't know how to call image in the image tag. 

`<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image_url[0] ); ?>">`

Comment: @KaranKcoresys If you used `$image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $term_featured_image_id );` to get the image url, then you can use `<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image_url[0] ); ?>">` as the url function returns either the image url as a string or a boolean false. Of course you can wrap the `img` in a `if`statement so that the img tag is not printed for nothing, if the function returns false and there's no url.

Comment: I also tried your function, I put those functions in the functions.php. I got this error: "Argument 1 passed to travel_trip_type_image_url() must be an instance of int, integer given" at "$term_img_url = travel_trip_type_image_url( $travel_location->term_id );"

Comment: @KaranKcoresys Ah, it looks like you're using an older PHP version, which doesn't support typesetting properly. Just remove `int`, `string`, and `WP_Query` which are on the function parameters. E.g. `travel_trip_type_image_url( int $term_id )` becomes `travel_trip_type_image_url( $term_id )`.

Comment: Thank you sir, I Upgrade php version and now error gone. But still code not working or not showing anything. Thank you sir for help.

Comment: @KaranKcoresys I updated the code with sample html output for the posts loop, which was missing earlier. Please also read the implementation steps I wrote at the end of my answer. The code is just an example and you might need to make some modifications to it to make it work in your exact setup. And if you don't have the required knowledge to do all the modifications you need, please consider hiring a professional developer to do the work for you.

Comment: I think that plugin is a problem, I asked plugin developers for support.